# Jenkins / Hudson: How to Build periodically only after another project are built

Tags: jenkins, hudson

I have a project (`p1`) that is built nightly.  Every Tuesday, I want to have a second project (`p2`) built, but only on successful completion of `p1`.  `p2` relies on successful build of `p1` so `p2` must not be triggered to run if that days' `p1` fails.

The only way I can think of doing this is to create two identical p1 jobs `p1a` and `p1b`:

- `p1a`  runs every day except tuesday
- `p1b` runs on tuesday, when finished successfully, triggers `p2`

This is a bit a mess however, as it creates multiple versions of `p1` to maintain, with their own build history, etc...

Anyone know a better way to accomplish this?

Comment: Do you want to **trigger** `p1` (again) before the `p2` build, or you just want to ensure that `p1` has finished for that day?

Comment: @Slav I want the day that p2 builds to ensure p1 has been finished successfully.

Comment: BTW, are you on *nix or Windows?

Comment: @Slav our Jenkins runs on a linux box

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an [**Exclusion**](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Exclusion-Plugin) plugin.

- Setup the same *"resource"* string for both jobs (read the plugin page for details)
- The `p1` job should be on a nightly schedule to start earlier than `p2` job
- The `p1` job should be on a Tuesday-only schedule to start slightly later than `p1`

This way, on Tuesdays, when `p2` runs, the *"resource"* will already be in-use by `p1`. I haven't actually used this plugin, so not sure if it will cause `p2` to wait or fail, but if the later is true, you can configure `p2` to retry failed builds with something like [this plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Retry+Failed+Builds+Plugin)

Alternatively, the [**Conditional Build Step**](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Conditional+BuildStep+Plugin) plugin can be used.

- In `p1` configure a **Conditional Build Step** *after* the building step (so if the building step fails, it never executes.
- It uses [**Run Condition**](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Run+Condition+Plugin) plugin, which will allow to select **Day of Week** as a condition. Select *Tuesday*
- Then use [**Parameterized Trigger Plugin**](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Trigger+Plugin) to add *Trigger/call builds on other projects* build step that will trigger `p2`

Comment: Didn't mention in OP, but p2 is dependent on p1 successfully running that day.  I updated my OP.  Locking a resource won't protect if p1 fails or never runs that day.

Comment: Would you consider having `p1` create a file on a shared filesystem, this file only being created on Tuesdays after successful `p1` execution. Then `p2` looks for the file. If found, it deletes the file, then runs the rest of `p2`. This way, if `p1` wasn't successful, there wouldn't be a file (and any previous week's files would have been deleted by previous week's `p2` execution. Doesn't matter if `p2` fails for whatever reason, as it would delete the file the first thing when it starts.

Comment: @Ray, added another alternative to answer

Comment: This looks promising.  Will attempt to setup these plugins as you mention.

Comment: Finally got back to this...  So the conditional build step on p1 to trigger p2 on given day is good, as long as the job doesn't need to be run for other things or multiple times (ideally we want the upstream job to monitor the downstream, so you can run p1 as many times you want, but p2 only gets triggered once at a given time).  There's a plugin to https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/BuildResultTrigger+Plugin that seems to do this, but too isn't a perfect fit for my need.  Since your second solution in your answer fits my OP, you're getting the love.

Answer (score 1):

There's a [stack overflow question on Conditional Post build steps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13091488/how-to-conditionally-build-other-projects) which might be of interest. In particular the post about the [conditional post build plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Post+build+task)

Perhaps using that plugin and getting the current day of the week using a custom script and verify it's tuesday would solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

You could set the starting time of both projects to the same (p2 a minute later or so).

Then you could define a lock (throttle concurrent build plugin or locks and latches) to allow only one of your jobs to run concurrently.

Alternatively, you could indeed create two jobs using the jobDSL plugin or something similar.

Comment: Interesting, but if p1 fails, fails to run, etc... p2 still runs.  I didn't mention they were dependent in my OP, but I'll update it

Comment: Personally, I would prefer the JobDSL solution (https://github.com/jenkinsci/job-dsl-plugin), because it leads to cleaner job chains and I use JobDSLs anyway, but Slav's updated solution is faster and has less prerequisites.

Answer (score 0):

I found a fairly recent plugin, BuildResultTrigger Plugin.  It allows conditional builds on multiple success of other jobs.  It also allows for scheduling, so it can be set to poll the other jobs for successful condition: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/BuildResultTrigger+Plugin

The one draw back is it's can't be 'triggered' by another job, but only by scheduled polling.