# Build job jenkins at specific commit to bitbucket

Tags: git, jenkins, bitbucket

i need start a build on Jenkins only when i push and commit with specific message to bitbucket. Actually work with webhooks but every push, the build starting. I have tried with git plugin and "Additional Behaviours" but not sure what is possible.

[image: Git configuration project page]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a weird requirement. You could create filter job which will be executed at each commit, check commit message and trigger your job only when necessary.

P.S. Found [Commit Message Trigger Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Commit+Message+Trigger+Plugin)

Comment: like this? https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Commit+Message+Trigger+Plugin

Comment: yes, this plugin will allow to use only job, but with skipped builds

Comment: I can create a separate job that check commit message and launch another job if the check result is true or false?

Comment: yes, you check GIT_COMMIT variable and create a file for example when you need to trigger a build using any approach - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13091488/how-to-conditionally-build-other-projects

Comment: I have resolved with Commit Message Trigger Plugin without create a filter job, thanks