# Conditional job chaining in jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

Let's assume I have 3 jobs in Jenkins

Job A, B, C

Is there any plugin that would allow me to chain these jobs so that when job A finishes, the build executes either job B or job C (never both). i.e. depending on a parameter passed to job A

Answer (score 5):

There's a ton of different ways to go about doing this..

1. Using something like a [Conditional BuildStep Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Conditional+BuildStep+Plugin) or [Run Condition Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Run+Condition+Plugin) to execute a certain build step containing a "trigger downstream job".
2. Using [Groovy Postbuild](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Groovy+Postbuild+Plugin) to execute a postbuild groovy script that will kick off job based on some logic (using the [Jenkins model](http://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/jenkins/model/Jenkins.html))
3. Using something like the [Build Flow Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Build+Flow+Plugin) to create a custom dsl script to do the branching.
4. Basically execute any shell, batch, or groovy script step that lets you do a conditionals along with the [jenkins rest api](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Remote+access+API) will probably work.

And here's a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13091488/how-to-conditionally-build-other-projects) on Stackoverflow regarding this.

Comment: There is also now the [Pipeline job](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline) in which you can embed conditional groovy logic.