# Run jenkins job without triggering downstream jobs

Tags: jenkins

I have a jenkins job with a couple of downstream jobs which are triggered upon the job finishing correctly.

There are times when I want to run the initial job without triggering the downstream jobs. Is this possible?

Comment: Have you looked at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13091488/how-to-conditionally-build-other-projects)? It probably contains some insightful leads.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the [conditional build step](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Conditional+BuildStep+Plugin) plugin might be of help. You can configure it to trigger other jobs based on various conditions, like so:

[image: conditional build step config example]

Here, the conditional build step has been configured to run `downstream-job` if foo.txt exists in the current workspace.